# fop in glassfish fail to render external resources

Tags: glassfish, apache-fop

I am generating a PDF file via fop 1.0 out of a java library. The unit tests are running fine and the PDF is rendered as expected, including an external graphic:

```
<fo:external-graphic content-width="20mm" src="url('images/image.png')" />
```

If I render this within a Java EE application in glassfish 3.1, I always get the following error:

```
Image not found. URI: images/image.png. (No context info available)
```

I double-checked whether the image is available. It is available within the .jar file in the .ear file and should therfore be available by the ClasspathUriResolver. This is a code-snipplet of how I setup the fop-factory:

```
FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
URIResolver uriResolver = new ClasspathUriResolver();
fopFactory.setURIResolver(uriResolver);
Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop(MimeConstants.MIME_PDF, out);
...
```

I also assigned the URI resolver to the TransformerFactory and the Transformer with no success. Would be great if someone can help me out.

-- Wintermute

Btw: the ClasspathUriResolver() looks like this

```
public class ClasspathUriResolver implements URIResolver {

  @Override
  public Source resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException {
    Source source = null;
    InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(href);
    if (inputStream != null) {
      source = new StreamSource(inputStream);
    }
    return source;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You consider a **different class loader** then `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(href);`

Try `InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(href);` or something else, maybe.

Does it work, then?

Comment: Hi towi, it is working! Thanks for the answer.It seems that using the static ClassLoader in the AppServer isn't a good idea - as always.